# Start a dependency unit in CoreOS

Tags: docker, coreos

I wish to deploy Wordpress on CoreOS using the official wordpress and mysql images from Docker. I can successfully start the MySql unit, however, the Wordpress unit cannot be started.

Here is the unit file for MySQL:

```
[Unit]
Description=MySQL DB
After=docker.service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=30
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker kill mysql1
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm mysql1
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull mysql
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --rm --name mysql1 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword mysql
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop mysql1

[X-Fleet]
Conflicts=mysql@*.service
```

And here is the unit file for Wordpress:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Wordpress
BindsTo=mysql@%i.service
After=mysql@%i.service

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=0
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker kill wordpress1
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm wordpress1
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull wordpress
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --rm --name wordpress1 --link mysql1:mysql -p 8080:80 wordpress
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop wordpress1

[X-Fleet]
MachineOf=mysql@*.service
```

I followed the tutorial on CoreOS doc to come up with such config.

I tried removing the BindsTo directive, but it does not help. I tried not using the MachineOf, and instead use the Conflict directive, but nothing changes. No unit was created, and there is no output. The command `fleetctl start wordpress@1.service` just returns immediately.

I would appreciate it if you could help me figure what is wrong with my config, and also if there are better ways to construct configs like this.

Comment: what is the output of `journalctl -u wordpress@1.service`  or `fleetctl journal wordpress@1.service` ?

Comment: Nothing. Such units were not created at all.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try telling fleet to start both units?

```
fleetctl start wordpress@1.service mysql@1.service
```

If you need more debugging information, `fleetctl --debug start` might have some clues, as would `journalctl --since today -u fleet`

Comment: Thanks Rob! I found out the answer thanks to your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Rob's answer, I found out that the wordpress unit has been launched, but got stuck in an infinite startup loop. The reason is because in the last line of the wordpress unit file, I should have `MachineOf=mysql@%i.service` instead of `MachineOf=mysql@*.service`. The typo made it that the service tries to find a machine that has such described service but cannot.